# asp.net setting up build process msbuild and cruise control

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

Where do I start , I need to set up a developement environment using msbuild and continuious integration, NUnit etc. I am quite new to this kind of thing as it is normally already set up in most environments ive worked in. I am quite short of time as well and dont have have the time to read huge volumes in order to get an understanding (developement starts Monday next week) so need to get this up and running asap in the shortest possible time. Does anyone have a working sample I can utilise or a short tutorial that breaks this process down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use CruiseControl.Net, and there are quite a few [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cruisecontrol.net+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) available.  If you have a specific question in regard to CCNET, feel free to post it.

I've also heard good things about [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).